# How to extract hyperlinks from docx file with php?

Tags: php, hyperlink, docx

Is there a way to extract hyperlinks from a docx file? I already know that there are ways to get the [images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756345/easiest-way-to-extract-images-from-a-ms-word-document-using-php) or the [content](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-extract-text-docx-or-odt-files-using-php) as plain text. But I got a docx file with thumbnails with hyperlinks. Using the mentioned content function I just receive this number for every thumbnail: 2933700. But how to filter the urls of the hyperlinks?

**Edit:**

Meanwhile I figured out that text links are saved in word/_rels/document.xml.rels (in the zip file) along with many links of the following kind: "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships". So there is a way to filter them. BUT I still don't know where the hyperlinks of the images are stored. It's strange. They have to be somewhere but where?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);
```

Comment: Thx! But what "$string" to use? Where in the zip file are the hyperlinks stored? They are not in the content (plain text).

Comment: $string is your string which you get from doc

Comment: No, I'm afraid it's not that easy. ;) The links are not in the "document.xml" file - there is only plain text. The text links are in a separate file named "document.xml.rels" (please have a look at my edit above). I have no idea where the image hyperlinks are stored at :(