# when i have upload docx file, content are storing in database How can i save image and insert image name in database?

Tags: php, mysql, docx

I have upload a docx file, all text are inserting into mysql database.
but i want upload docx file such as 
[word image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHB8T.png)

How can i save Image1, Image3, Image4 and insert these into option_one, option_three, option_four.

Here is database format:
[mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsIsf.png)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to extract images from a MS Word Document using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756345/easiest-way-to-extract-images-from-a-ms-word-document-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

`.docx` files are in fact zip files.

You will have to save the uploaded file, rename it as a .zip file then unzip its contents.

You will then have access to the full size images stored inside the `.docx`

Comment: Funny how they just come and go, *huh?*